# how can i reset the child attributes of a container using renderer?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In a container i have dropdown and multiple selects and quantity select. 
On a click of a button i want to reset the state of a component.

[image: My component]

```
  <input #select type="checkbox"  value="somevalue"/>
```

In component i have a viewChildren

```
@ViewChildren('select') selectReference:QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

And on click event of button i am trying something like this:

```
 submitProduct(){
      for(let currentelRef of this.selectReference.toArray()){
        console.log(currentelRef);
        this.render.setProperty(this.selectReference,'checked',false);
      }
}
```

but this is not working. 
How can i achieve this ?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `ngModel`, or a `FormGroup` and then just set the model to false in your component. No need to query for the checkboxes that way.

But, if you want to use Renderer, you'll need to target the `nativeElement` of each `ElementRef`:

```
this.render.setProperty(currentelRef.nativeElement, "checked", false);
```